# Ada dynamic array instantiation

Tags: generics, ada, gnat

Building on [this instructive question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429604/indexer-and-reference-type-for-dynamic-arrays-in-ada), I'm having difficulty instantiating the array:

DynamicArrays.ads

```
    generic
        type Value_Type is private;
        
    package DynamicArrays is

        type Dynamic_Array is tagged private;

        function Length (Self : Dynamic_Array) return Natural with Inline;

    private
        type Static_Array is array (Positive range <>) of aliased Value_Type;
        type Static_Array_Access is access all Static_Array;

        type Dynamic_Array is tagged record
            Backing : Static_Array_Access;
        end record with
          Variable_Indexing => Variable_Indexer;

        type Variable_Reference (Data : access Value_Type) is null record with
          Implicit_Dereference => Data;
        
        function Variable_Indexer (Self : in out  Dynamic_Array; Indexer : Positive)
                                         return Variable_Reference with Pre => Indexer <= Self.Length;
    end DynamicArrays;
```

DynamicArrays.adb

```
    package body DynamicArrays is

        function Variable_Indexer (Self : in out Dynamic_Array; Indexer : Positive) return Variable_Reference is
        begin
            return Variable_Reference'(Data => Self.Backing (Index)'Access);
        end Variable_Indexer;
        
    end DynamicArrays;
```

Main.adb

```
    with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
    with DynamicArrays;
    procedure Main is

        --! 5:9 Indexing aspect cannot be specified on full view if partial view is tagged
        --! 5:9 instantiation error at dynamicarrays.ads:21
        package IntegerDA is new DynamicArrays (Value_Type => Integer);
        use IntegerDA;

        --! 7:14 subtype mark required in this context
        DA : Integerda := 'a' & 'b' & 'c';
        
    begin
        --! 10:24 invalid prefix in selected component "DA"
        pragma Assert (DA.Length = 3);
        pragma Assert (DA (1) = 'a');
        pragma Assert (DA (2) = 'b');
        pragma Assert (DA (3) = 'c');
    end Main;
```

Exclamation marks => the compiler's errors (Gnat 2020).

I realise that I'm a noob at Ada, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have instantiated a new package, and then tried to declare an array, using the name of the package NOT the name of the array type exported by that package : `DA : IntegerDA.Dynamic_Array := ...` (Note also that 'a' etc are not Integers...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I'd tried that but but then I get [5:34 "Dynamic_Array" is not visible], which I don't understand, as it's in the public part part of dynamicarrays's spec

Comment: The fact that it's an array is not visible... you may need to expose that (in opposition no making it tagged) or add a constructor function ("object factory" in Design Pattern language)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Erm, sorry, you've lost me there. Could you possibly post an answer that works (pretty please)?

Comment: The detailed composition of your Dynamic_Array type is private, and is therefore not visible to the public. You will need to either make the Dynamic_Array type public (not private) or provide public procedures and / or functions to manipulate the contents of the Dynamic_Array type.

Comment: You seem to think that the characters 'a', 'b' and 'c' are integers. They are not integers. They are characters.

Comment: You might want to look at package [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-2.html), which successfully does this. The full [GNAT implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/libgnat/a-convec.ads;h=1d257a05bed6e402b8d2c243e0b48219eafbb802;hb=refs/heads/master) includes the private part and body.