# How to implement Unchecked_Access

Tags: arrays, ada, gnat

I am trying, [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66049769/338101), to design a 2D array that expands automagically.

Rectangular.ads

```
generic
    type Value_Type is private;

package Rectangular is
    
    function Get ( Row, Col : Integer) return Value_Type;
    procedure Set ( Row, Col : Integer; Value : Value_Type);
    
private
    type Matrix is array (Integer range <>, Integer range <>) of aliased Value_Type;
    
    Item : access Matrix;
    
end Rectangular;
```

Rectangular.adb

```
package body Rectangular is

    function Create (Rowmin, Rowmax, Colmin, Colmax : Integer) return access Matrix is
    begin
        return Answer :  constant access Matrix :=
          new Matrix (Rowmin .. Rowmax, Colmin .. Colmax)
        do
            null; -- maybe something later...
        end return;
    end Create;
    
    procedure Adjust_Bounds (Row, Col : Integer) is
        
        Rowmin, Rowmax, Colmin, Colmax : Integer;
        Newitem :  access Matrix;
        
    begin
        
        if Row >= Item'First (1) and Row <= Item'Last (1) and
          Col >= Item'First (2) and Col <= Item'Last (2) then
            return;
        end if;

        -- Matrix needs expanding, establish new bounds
        Rowmin := Integer'Min (Item'First (1), Row);
        Rowmax := Integer'Min (Item'Last (1), Row);
        Colmin := Integer'Min (Item'First (2), Col);
        Colmax := Integer'Min (Item'Last (2), Col);
    
        Newitem := Create (Rowmin, Rowmax, Colmin, Colmax);
        
        -- Copy old to new
        for R in Item'Range (1) loop
            for C in Item'Range (2) loop
                Newitem (R, C) := Item (R, C);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        
        -- How to free Item here?
        Item := Newitem;
        
    end Adjust_Bounds;
    
    function Get (Row, Col : Integer) return Value_Type is
        Result : Value_Type;
    begin
        Adjust_Bounds (Row, Col);
        Result := Item (Row, Col);
        return Result;
    end Get;
    
    procedure Set ( Row, Col : Integer; Value : Value_Type) is
    begin
        Adjust_Bounds (Row, Col);
        Item (Row, Col) := Value;
    end Set;
    
begin
    Item := Create (0, 0, 0, 0);

end Rectangular;
```

main.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Rectangular;
procedure Main is
begin
    declare
        package Rect is new Rectangular (Value_Type => Integer);
        X : Integer;
    begin
        -- Only 0,0 exists initially
        Rect.Set (0, 0, 2);
        X := Rect.Get (0, 0);
        Put_Line (X'Image);
        
        -- Make the matrix expand
        Rect.Set (1, 1, 42);
        X := Rect.Get (1, 1);
        Put_Line (X'Image);
    end;
end Main;
```

This compiles, but with

```
   6:17 warning: "Program_Error" will be raised at run time
   6:17 warning: accessibility check failure
   6:17 warning: in instantiation at rectangular.adb:29
```

and I of course get "raised PROGRAM_ERROR : rectangular.adb:59 accessibility check failed" when I try and run it.

I don't understand why, as 'Rect' is not clearly accessible outside the scope of the block;

1. Should I use Unchecked_Access to avoid this behaviour? If so, what would it look like?
2. If not, what is the correct idiom?
3. How should I free 'Item' in Rectangular.adb?

I've been trying to get this to work for several days with no success, help with working code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use Ada.Containers.

Comment: don't use anonymous access types.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ada.Containers hasn't got 2-dimensional arrays as far as I understand. My use case is a matrix(rows,columns:integer) of 1-byte states representing an area on the ground; the map has to expand as the robot discovers new terrain. A vector of vectors seems clumsy and a Map would use a lot of storage with pointers to a 1-byte flag. Coming from .Net, I may have completely misunderstood the Ada philosophy, any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: @egilhh Which part of my code has an anonymous access type? Is 'access matrix' anonymous?

Comment: @smirkingman, yes all of the places where you have `access Matrix` are anonymous, and thus a different type from the others, with different accessibility levels

Comment: @smirkingman, Are you sure a map isn't a better fit for this problem? A 2-dimensional array expands exponentialy in memory usage every time your robot steps outside the current bounds, wasting whole scan lines woorth of memory... Not to mention all the copying going on that will keep on slowing down your program as your robot explores

Comment: @egilhh Good point, yes, and no. The matrix only expands when the robot (a mower as it happens) is exploring. Once it's discovered the entire garden the matrix is more-or-less fixed, so it doesn't matter if exploring is expensive. Using one byte for the state of each 10cm square, that's only 300Kb for a 3'000 square-metre garden, which would easily fit in the cache of a little SBC.

Comment: @smirkingman if you know the size in advance you could just pre-allocate a fixed array, no access types neccessary

Comment: Ada.Containers provides the Vector type, which roughly corresponds to an expandable one-dimensional array. One can mimic an expandable two-dimensional array by creating a vector containing elements of another vector. This is roughly equivalent to making an array of arrays.

Comment: Why do you have a private part? You have no private types and no child packages.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter You're right there's no need for the private part, everything *could* be public. That said, the least you expose publicly, the less there is to break later.

Comment: They don't need to be public; they can be in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add after `type Matrix`

```
type Matrix_P is access Matrix;
```

(use your own convention for naming access types).

Then, globally replace `access Matrix` by `Matrix_P`.

Then, in `Adjust_Bounds`, you appear to need to replace

```
      Rowmax := Integer'Min (Item'Last (1), Row);
```

by

```
      Rowmax := Integer'Max (Item'Last (1), Row);
```

and likewise for `Colmax`.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I hadn't understood that 'access matrix' is anonymous. Works nicely now. Could I possibly ask you how I 'free' the old matrix please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might consider making your expandable matrix using the pattern shown in the following package specification:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
generic
   type Index_Type is range <>;
   with package inner_vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(<>);
package Vector_Of_Vectors is
   package V_Matrix is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Index_Type   => Index_Type,
                                                  Element_Type => Inner_Vector.Vector,
                                                  "="          => Inner_Vector."=");
   use Inner_Vector;
end Vector_Of_Vectors;
```

This pattern will conceptually mimic an array of arrays

```
type foo is array (Positive range 1..10) of Integer;
type bar is array (Natural range 0..9) of foo;
```

You will now be able to modify the length of each vector element of type V_Matrix as well as add more vector elements to V_Matrix.

Following is a small example of instantiating the Vector_Of_Vectors package:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Vector_Of_Vectors;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Containers;

procedure Main is
   package Int_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Index_Type => Natural,
                                                    Element_Type => Integer);
   use Int_Vector;
   
   package Int_Matrix is new Vector_Of_Vectors(Index_Type   => Natural,
                                               inner_vector => Int_Vector);
   use Int_Matrix;
   
   Temp_Vect : Int_Vector.Vector;
   Temp_Mat  : V_Matrix.Vector;
begin

   Temp_Vect := Int_Vector.Empty_Vector;
   for I in 1..5 loop
      Temp_Vect.append(I);
   end loop;
   
   Temp_Mat.Append(Temp_Vect);
    
   temp_Vect := Int_Vector.Empty_Vector;
    
   for I in 15..25 loop
      Temp_Vect.append(I);
   end loop;
   Temp_Mat.Append(Temp_Vect);
     
   for V of Temp_Mat loop
      for I of V loop
         Put(I'Image);
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I instantiate it? package Rect is new Vector_Of_Vectors (Index_Type => Integer, Inner_Vector => ???

Comment: Example for Integer values: package Int_Vect is new Ada.Containers.Vector(Index_type => Natural, Element_Type => Integer);   package int_matrix is new Vector_Of_Vectors (Integer, Int_Vect);

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Unfortunately vectors can't seem work in my use case: Say I have a Vector_of_Vectors(occupied: Boolean), that is empty. I Append(0,0) and set it to Occupied:=False because I'm standing there. I want to know if Cell(5,5) is occupied (I intend to move along (1,1)..(5,5)). I can't say If cell(5,5)=Occupied because none of the vectors have anything from (1..5,1..5), so I'm obliged to append empty entries (1..5,1..5) before I can refer to cell(5,5). Or have I totally misunderstood something?

Comment: If you use an array you will create the array and initialize its elements with a value such as False or True. You will then modify each element in the array according to the rules of your application. You can do the same with vectors. Granted, the syntax for accessing vector elements is more verbose than for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution for a dynamically self-adjusting 2D array. Usage:

```
package Rect is new Rectangular (Element => Float, Default => 0.0);
use Rect;
Map : Rect.Matrix;
...
Map(-25, 97) := 42.0;
```

Re-allocating the underlying array would be unacceptably costly if it happened at each size increase, so the package allocates a little more than is necessary to reduce the re-allocations.

The sample Main continuously expands an array until the heap is exhausted, noting the time for each re-allocation. I was pleasantly surprised at the speed of the compiled code, a re-allocation of 1_000 X 1_000 array (1_000_000 elements) takes only ~5 mS:
[image: Re-allocation timing]

Here's the output, ran on an [AMD 3960X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-threadripper-3960x):

```
Resized to  0..10, 0..10 =  1 entries in  0.000002100 s
Resized to  0..24, 0..24 =  121 entries in  0.000001500 s
Resized to  0..54, 0..54 =  625 entries in  0.000011800 s
Resized to  0..118, 0..118 =  3025 entries in  0.000033200 s
Resized to  0..254, 0..254 =  14161 entries in  0.000116400 s
Resized to  0..541, 0..541 =  65025 entries in  0.000204300 s
Resized to  0..1143, 0..1143 =  293764 entries in  0.000889200 s
Resized to  0..2400, 0..2400 =  1308736 entries in  0.004220100 s
Resized to  0..5015, 0..5015 =  5764801 entries in  0.017126300 s
Resized to  0..10439, 0..10439 =  25160256 entries in  0.072370300 s
 10000 X  10000 is  381Mb
Resized to  0..21661, 0..21661 =  108993600 entries in  0.328238800 s
 20000 X  20000 is  1525Mb
Resized to  0..44827, 0..44827 =  469242244 entries in  1.432776000 s
 30000 X  30000 is  3433Mb
 40000 X  40000 is  6103Mb
Resized to  0..92556, 0..92556 =  2009549584 entries in  56.372428000 s
 50000 X  50000 is  9536Mb
 60000 X  60000 is  13732Mb
 70000 X  70000 is  18692Mb
 80000 X  80000 is  24414Mb
 90000 X  90000 is  30899Mb

raised STORAGE_ERROR : System.Memory.Alloc: heap exhausted
```

The STORAGE_ERROR is as expected, I have 32Gb of memory.

**This is one of my first efforts in Ada, critiques would be very welcome**.

main.ads

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Assertions; use Ada.Assertions;
with Rectangular;

procedure Main is
    
    subtype Element is Float;
    
    Default_Value : Element := 42.0;
    
    package Rect is new Rectangular (Element => Element, Default => Default_Value);
    use Rect;
    Map : Rect.Matrix;
    
begin
    declare -- warmup, ensure values get set and defaults are applied
    begin
        Map (0, 0) := 2.3;
        Map (10, 10) := Map (0, 0) + 1.0;
        Assert (Map (0, 0) = 2.3);
        Assert (Map (10, 10) = 3.3);
        Assert (Map (5, 5) = Default_Value);
    end;
    
    declare -- Exercise hard to get reallocation timings
        Bytes           : Long_Long_Integer;
        MBytes          : Long_Long_Integer;
        ILong           : Long_Long_Integer;
        Current, Should : Element;
    begin
        for I in 0 .. 100_000 loop

            Map (I, I) := Element (I * 3);
            
            if I mod 10_000 = 0 then -- occasionally
                
                -- Check every value. On diagonal=3*, Off diagonal=Default_Value
                for Row in 0 .. I loop
                    for Col in 0 .. I loop
                        Current := Map (Row, Col );
                        if Row = Col then
                            Should := Element (Row * 3);
                        else
                            Should := Default_Value;
                        end if;
                        Assert (Current = Should);
                    end loop;
                end loop;
                
                -- Show progress
                ILong := Long_Long_Integer (I);
                Bytes := Ilong * Ilong * Long_Long_Integer (Element'Size) / 8;
                MBytes := Bytes / 2 ** 20;
                Put_Line (I'Image & " X " & I'Image & " is " & MBytes'Image & "Mb");
            end if;
        end loop;
    end;
end Main;
```

Rectangular.ads

```
generic
    type Element is private;
    Default : Element;

package Rectangular is
-- Provides an X..Y matrix of Element, which can be used just like a 2D Array.
-- The bounds of the array adjust themselves to accomodate requested indexes.
-- Rule-of-thumb: ~5 millseconds to re-allocate an array of 1'000'000 (1'000 x 1'000) entries. YMMV.
-- Usage:
--    package Rect is new Rectangular (Element => Float, Default => 0.0);
--    use Rect;
--    Map : Rect.Matrix;
--    ...
--    Map(-25, 97) := 42.0;
-- The bounds are now -25..0, 0..97, 2'548 elements, all 0.0 except -25,97 = 42.0
    
    type Matrix is tagged limited private
      with 
         Constant_Indexing => Get_Element,
         Variable_Indexing => Get_Reference;

    type Element_Access is access all Element;

    function Get_Element (M : in out Matrix; E : in Element_Access) return Element;

    function Get_Element (M : in out Matrix; Row, Col : in Integer) return Element;

    type Reference (R : access Element) is limited null record
      with Implicit_Dereference => R;

    function Get_Reference (M : in out Matrix; E : in Element_Access) return Reference;

    function Get_Reference (M : in out Matrix; Row, Col : in Integer) return Reference;

private
    type Backing is array (Integer range <>, Integer range <>) of Element;
    type Backing_Access is access Backing;
    type Matrix is tagged limited record
        Items : Backing_Access;
    end record;
end Rectangular;
```

Rectangular.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar; use Ada.Calendar;
with Ada.Strings; use Ada.Strings;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed; use Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;

package body Rectangular is

    Demo : constant Boolean := True; -- Set to False once you've watched the demo
    
    function Create (Row_First, Row_Last, Col_First, Col_Last : Integer) return Backing_Access is
    -- Create a Backing array of Element'Access with (possibly negative) bounds
    begin
        return Answer :  Backing_Access :=
          new Backing (Row_First .. Row_Last, Col_First .. Col_Last)
        do
            for I in Row_First .. Row_Last loop
                for J in Col_First .. Col_Last loop
                    Answer (I, J) := Default;
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end return;
    end Create;
    
    function Multiplier (Bounds : Integer) return Float is
    -- From the bounds of an array, calculate a suitable, gentle increase
    -- Bounds | Log/(1+bounds,2) | 1/That | Increase
    --       1         1.0          1.000         1 
    --      10         3.5          0.289         3 
    --     100         6.7          0.150        15 
    --   1,000        10.0          0.100       100 
    --   5,000        12.3          0.081       407 
    --  10,000        13.3          0.075       753 
    --  25,000        14.6          0.068     1,711 
    -- 100,000        16.6          0.060     6,021 
    --
    -- So, for a matrix bound (row or column) that is 25'000, 
    -- the matrix will be resized to 25'000+1'711=26'711
    
        package Floats is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions (Float);
        Factor, Result : Float;
    begin
        Factor := Floats.Log (Float (1 + Bounds), 2.0);
        Result := 1.0 + 1.0 / Factor;
        -- Put_Line (Bounds'Image & ' ' & Factor'Image & ' ' & Result'Image);
        return Result;
    end Multiplier;
    
    procedure Free is new Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation (Backing, Backing_Access);
    -- Release a Backing.
    -- We know that this is safe, as they are private and only *we* can allocate them
    
    procedure Adjust_Bounds (M : in out Matrix; Row, Col : in Integer) is
    -- Check to see if Row-Col is within the current bounds.
    -- If not, enlarge the Backing to accomodate said Row-Col
    begin
        if M.Items = null then -- auto-initialise
            M.Items := Create (Row, Row, Col, Col);
        end if;
            
        if Row >= M.Items'First (1) and Row <= M.Items'Last (1) and
          Col >= M.Items'First (2) and Col <= M.Items'Last (2) then
            return; -- In bounds, all is well
        end if;
        
        declare
            Enlarged                       : Backing_Access;
            Row_First, Row_Last            : Integer;
            Col_First, Col_Last            : Integer;
            Row_Range, Col_Range           : Integer;
            Row_Multiplier, Col_Multiplier : Float;
            Start_Time, End_Time           : Time;
        
        begin
            if Demo then
                Start_Time := Clock;
            end if;
            Row_First := M.Items'First (1);
            Row_Last := M.Items'Last (1);
            Row_Range := Row_Last - Row_First + 1;
            Row_Multiplier := Multiplier (Row_Range);
        
            Col_First := M.Items'First (2);
            Col_Last := M.Items'Last (2);
            Col_Range := Col_Last - Col_First + 1;
            Col_Multiplier := Multiplier (Col_Range); 

            -- Integer'Min because the requested index may be further out than our conservative expansion multiplier
            if Row < Row_First then
                Row_First := Integer'Min (Row, Row_First - Integer (Float (Row_Range) * Row_Multiplier));
            elsif Row > Row_Last then
                Row_Last := Integer'Max (Row, Row_Last + Integer (Float (Row_Range) * Row_Multiplier));
            end if;
        
        
            if Col < Col_First then
                Col_First := Integer'Min (Col, Col_First - Integer (Float (Col_Range) * Col_Multiplier));
            elsif Col > Col_Last then
                Col_Last := Integer'Max (Col, Col_Last + Integer (Float (Col_Range) * Col_Multiplier));
            end if;

            Enlarged := Create (Row_First, Row_Last, Col_First, Col_Last);

            -- Copy old to new
            for R in M.Items'Range (1) loop
                for C in M.Items'Range (2) loop
                    Enlarged (R, C) := M.Items (R, C);
                end loop;
            end loop;
        
            Free (M.Items);
            M.Items := Enlarged;
            
            -- just for demonstration
            if Demo then
                declare
                    Seconds : Duration;
                    Size    : Long_Long_Integer := Long_Long_Integer (Row_Range) * Long_Long_Integer (Col_Range);
                begin
                    End_Time := Clock;
                    Seconds := End_Time - Start_Time;
                    Row_Range := Row_Last - Row_First + 1;
                    Col_Range := Col_Last - Col_First + 1;
                    Put_Line ("Resized to " & Row_First'Image & ".." & Trim (Row_Last'Image, Left) & ',' & 
                      Col_First'Image & ".." & Trim (Col_Last'Image, Left) & 
                      " = " & Size'Image & " entries in " & Duration'Image (Seconds) & " s");
                end;
            end if;
        end;
        
    end Adjust_Bounds;
    
    function Get_Reference (M : in out Matrix; E : in Element_Access) return Reference is
      (Reference'(R => E));

    function Get_Element (M : in out Matrix; E : in Element_Access) return Element is
      (M (E));

    function Get_Element (M : in out Matrix; Row, Col : in Integer) return Element is
        Result : Element;
    begin
        Adjust_Bounds (M, Row, Col);
        Result := M.Items (Row, Col);
        return Result;
    end Get_Element;

    function Get_Reference (M : in out Matrix; Row, Col : in Integer) return Reference is
    begin
        Adjust_Bounds (M, Row, Col);
        -- Unrestricted_Access is wicked, but we know what we're doing and it's the only way
        return Answer : Reference :=
          Reference'(R => M.Items ( Row, Col)'Unrestricted_Access);
    end Get_Reference;
    
end Rectangular;
```